# Merging two files horizontally and formatting

Tags: unix, paste

I have two files as follows:

File_1

```
Austin
Los Angeles
York
San Ramon
```

File_2

```
Texas
California
New York
California
```

I want to merge them horizontally as follows:

```
Austin       Texas
Los Angeles  California
York         New York
San Ramon    California
```

I am able to merge horizontally by using `paste` command, but the formatting is going haywire.

```
Austin Texas
Los Angeles California
York New York
San Ramon California
```

I realize that `paste` is working as it is supposed to, but can someone point me in the right direction to get the formatting right.

Thanks.

Comment: First, I removed all the tabs from both the file. Then, to the first file, I added 25 spaces to the end of all line. I did a `paste` on this file, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

paste is using a tab when 'merging' the file, so maybe you have to post-process the file and remove the tab with spaces:

```
paste File_1 File_2 | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } ; {printf("%-20s%s\n",$1,$2) }'
```

result:

```
Austin              Texas
Los Angeles         California
York                New York
San Ramon           California
```

Comment: for example with awk:
paste a b | awk '{printf("%-20s%s\n",$1,$2) }'

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to check number of characters in the longest line. Than you may use fmt to pad line from the first file to greater length. Finish it using paste.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an idea about the field width, you could do something like this:

```
IFS_BAK="$IFS"
IFS=$'\t'
paste file_1 file_2 \
| while read city state; do 
    printf "%-15s %-15s\n" "$city" "$state"
  done
IFS="$IFS_BAK"
```

Or this shorter version:

```
paste file_1 file_2 | while IFS=$'\t' read city state; do
  printf "%-15s %-15s\n" "$city" "$state"
done
```

Or use the `column` tool from `bsdmainutils`:

```
paste file_1 file_2 | column -s $'\t' -t
```